# Weird error Inserting With Linq to SQL

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I'm having a strange problem inserting a row using Linq To SQL, I'm being asked to write a program without use Entity Framework, so I'm figuring how to make this and I'm following a Linq to SQL tutorial.

When I try to insert a row I get this exception:

> System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeException: No se puede modificar la
>   columna. [ Column name = id ]

Is Linq is trying to modify a column?, this is my entity, when I remove the `Association` field I'm able to persist without problem.

```
[Table(Name="Usuario")]
public class Usuario
{
    [Column(IsPrimaryKey = true, IsDbGenerated = true, AutoSync = AutoSync.OnInsert,Name="id")]
    public int id { get; set; }
    [Column]
    public string nombre { get; set; }
    [Column]
    public string direccion { get; set; }
    [Column]
    public string telefono { get; set; }
    [Column]
    public string codigoPostal { get; set; }

    private EntityRef<Ciudad> _ciudad;

    [Association (Storage="_ciudad",ThisKey="ciudad",OtherKey="id")]
    public Ciudad ciudad {
        get {return this._ciudad.Entity;}
        set { this._ciudad.Entity = value; }
    }

    private EntityRef<TipoUsuario> _tipoUsuario;

    [Association (Storage="_tipoUsuario",ThisKey="tipoUsuario",OtherKey="id")]
    public  TipoUsuario tipoUsuario {
        get {return this._tipoUsuario.Entity;}
        set { this._tipoUsuario.Entity = value; }
    }
}
```

Update:

Here is when I'm trying to persist:

```
public override void agregar(Usuario obj)
{
    System.Data.Linq.Table<Usuario> usrs = context.GetTable<Usuario>();
    usrs.InsertOnSubmit(obj);

    try
    {
       context.SubmitChanges();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
    }
}
```

And this is my controller :

```
public class UsuarioController : Controller
{
    UsuarioRepository dao = new UsuarioRepository();

    ...

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(Usuario u)
    {
        //try
        //{
        dao.agregar(u);
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
        //}
        //catch
        //{
        //    return View();
        //}
    }
   ...
}
```

Comment: Where is you are trying to insert record in DB using LINQ to SQL?

Comment: Sorry I have updated my post and added the block where I'm trying to persist

Answer (score 0):

The "Id" column is both set to PrimaryKey and DbGenerated. Probably before inserting the "obj" object somehow you are modifying the value of Id which causes this exception.

Comment: the value for id is 0 when I try to persist,    that block is the only code I have in my "add" method :/

Comment: so where does that "obj" come from? you pass it to your add method? or it is bound to an UI element or something? and also have you set the IsIdentity attribute in your table?(causes automatic increment)

Comment: Thanks for your answer,  I'm using a controller and the view never set any value for the id field. I have updated the question with the content of  Controller class..

Comment: yw. so depending on your business you should decide whether the Id must be autogenerated or not. if it should not be autogenerated before inserting the object you must set a value for the Id property, else you must set the IsIdentity of this column to "Yes" in your table design mode.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I made this work

The problem was my Storage, in fact, it causes a stackoverflow exception because is pointing to itself.

So I had to make some changes, renaming my FK columns on "Usuario" table and adding this column to my model, then set the "thiskey" and "otherkey" values and adding "isforeignkey=true".

This is my final model for "usuario" :

```
namespace Project.Models
{
    [Table(Name="Usuario")]
    public class Usuario
    {
        [Column(IsPrimaryKey = true, IsDbGenerated = true)]
        public int id { get; set; }
        [Column]
        public string nombre { get; set; }
        [Column]
        public string direccion { get; set; }
        [Column]
        public string telefono { get; set; }
        [Column]
        public string codigoPostal { get; set; }
        [Column]
        public Int32 tipoUsuarioId { get; set; }
        [Column]
        public Int32 ciudadId { get; set; }


        private EntityRef<Ciudad> _ciudad;
        [Association(Storage = "_ciudad", Name = "FK_USUARIO_CIUDAD", OtherKey = "id", ThisKey = "ciudadId", IsForeignKey = true)]
        public Ciudad ciudad {
            get {return this._ciudad.Entity;}
            set { this._ciudad.Entity = value; }
        }

        private EntityRef<TipoUsuario> _tipoUsuario = new EntityRef<TipoUsuario>();
        [Association (Storage="_tipoUsuario",Name="FK_USUARIO_TIPOUSUARIO",OtherKey="id",ThisKey="tipoUsuarioId",IsForeignKey=true)]
        public  TipoUsuario tipoUsuario { 
            get {return this._tipoUsuario.Entity;}
            set { this._tipoUsuario.Entity = value; }
        }

    }
```

Thanks to @aminexplo for your help :)